# Sort paths found by DFS by its length in C

Tags: c, sorting, graph, depth-first-search

I need little help with DFS algorithm. I programmed application in C, that finds all possible paths between two vertexes in given graph.

The result (between vertexes 1 and 6) is in this format/order:

1-5-6,
1-6,
1-7-6

But my desire is to have them sorted by its length like this:

1-6,
1-5-6,
1-7-6

But I don't know how to sort them. For now whenever I find a new path I immediately print it to console output. I am sure that there is a way, how to do. Right now I cannot find it, so I am asking for help.

Thanks for answers.

EDIT

Example code, how I print paths, I reverse stack to have them in a correct order.

```
Stack *reverse = stack_new();

/* copy data of stack */
Node *temp = path->head;
while(temp != NULL)
{
    stack_push(reverse, temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}

if(reverse->size >= 1)
{
    printf("%d", stack_pop(reverse));
}
while(stack_empty(reverse) == 0)
{
    printf("-%d", stack_pop(reverse));
}
printf(";");
free(reverse);
```

Comment: Store them, sort them, print them. What's difficult?

Comment: Don't print, record. Use a singly-linked list to retain the paths; but instead of inserting always at the front (or at the end), insert into the correct position according to length. We can't give more detailed help, because you have shown no code yourself.

Comment: Many thanks for both answers. I added code, how I print paths. A thought that linked list could do the work, but I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: A linked list could be one way of storing the results — other ways are possible.  A linked list is fine.  Is length measured by 'number of nodes' in the path, or do you have auxilliary information that gives the distance between two nodes?

Comment: Primary is measured by 'number of nodes' in the path, in case where the number is the same there is also the secondary number (metric), which is computed like difference between 'oldest' and 'newest' edge in path (for example 2007-10-11,2000-01-02;2839), each edge in graph has got date as distance parameter.

Comment: @awarus can you post the whole code ?

Comment: @zenwraight I can, but I already implemented linked list solution. Thanks for all answers. Now I don't know how to keep list sorted by two criterias.